# IN postgreSql how to provide manually create array to the operator "IN"?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to do the the following? If not is there any alternative way?

I am trying to something like this

```
DO
$$
    DECLARE
    user_name_list TEXT[] := '{"aa", "cc"}';

    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM "basic-test" WHERE username IN user_name_list;
    END;
$$;
```

But getting error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "user_name_list"
LINE 7: ...       DELETE FROM "basic-test" WHERE username IN user_name_...
                                                             ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 126
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `= any( <array> )`

```
DELETE FROM "basic-test" WHERE username = any(user_name_list);
```